# How to integrate an sms login in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

Please tell me how to integrate sms based login in asp.net core ?
Is there a way to send SMS from an ASP.NET website using a Web API? I know about web services, but don't know how to call those services from my app

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1

Comment: can you please tell another solution for this like Twilio integration?